# Converting from POSIXct to character in R

Tags: r, data-conversion, posixct

I have a POSIXct datetime column in a file.

```
$date
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
"2005-10-13 14:13:08 UTC"
```

I would like to convert it to character column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast your POSIXCT object to character, e.g.

```
date <- as.POSIXct("20-Jan-2018 19:06:08.314", format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%OS")
date.str <- as.character(date)
date.str

[1] "2018-01-20 19:06:08"
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! Once I apply df$date.str <- as.character(df$date)
> df$date.str, it prints the column date in correct format, but then when I check lapply(df, class), I get POSIXct again. Do you know how can I apply the modified column to dataframe?

Comment: You should be able to just use `as.character` on the entire POSIXCT column.

Comment: df[, 1] <- sapply(df[, 1], as.character) changes a column format in all dataframe. Thank you once again Tim!

Comment: I noticed that using as.character() to POSIXct objects can mess up the date format if there's a datetime with HH:MM:SS equal to 00:00:00, because as.character takes out all that part. For instance, if you had POSIXct instace with value: "2022-03-12 00:00:00 CET" and you use as.character() the output will be: "2022-03-12". If you want to keep the string format in cases of 0 values, you will need to use strftime(), for instance: strftime("2022-03-12 00:00:00 CET", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Madrid") returns "2022-03-12 00:00:00".